# CHM files broken on a new Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, chm

When I try and browse CHM files on my new Windows 7 Home Premium installation, every page gives me the following error:

*Navigation to the webpage was canceled*
*What you can try:     Retype the address*

I am assuming the files are not corrupt, as the contents and index display correctly.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.scottleckie.com/2009/05/downloaded-chm-help-file-shows-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-cancelled/

Comment: If that solves it, nice one.

Comment: You are a star!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use a different chm reader that doesn't have this problem.

Both xchm (http://xchm.sourceforge.net/) and Sumatra PDF (http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) are free, open-source and don't have this problem when opening chm documents.